# TCP Client - loop in communication

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a program which goal is to communicate with the weight terminal using TCP client. 
I'm sending specified messages (eg. checking status) and depending on the replies I'm making some another process.
First, some code.
Connection:

```
public static void PolaczZWaga(string IP, int port)
    {
        IP = IP.Replace(" ", "");
        KlientTCP = new TcpClient();
        KlientTCP.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
    }
```

Sending message (eg. checking status)

```
public static string OdczytDanychZWagi(byte[] WysylaneZapytanie)
    {
        // Wysyłka komunikatu do podłączonego serwera TCP
        byte[] GotoweZapytanie = KomunikatyWspolne.PoczatekKomunikacji.Concat(WysylaneZapytanie).Concat(KomunikatyWspolne.KoniecKumunikacji).ToArray();
        NetworkStream stream = KlientTCP.GetStream();
        stream.Write(GotoweZapytanie, 0, GotoweZapytanie.Length);

        // Otrzymanie odpowiedzi

        // Buffor na odpowiedz
        byte[] odpowiedz = new Byte[256];

        // String do przechowywania odpowiedzi w ASCII
        String responseData = String.Empty;

        // Odczyt danych z serwera
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(odpowiedz, 0, odpowiedz.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(odpowiedz, 0, bytes);
        return responseData;
    }
```

After Form1 open I make an connection and checking status

string odp = KomunikacjaSieciowa.OdczytDanychZWagi(OdczytZWagi.Kom_RejestrStatusu);
                char status = odp[0];

```
            switch(status)
            {
                case 'B':
                    KomunikacjaSieciowa.WysylkaDoWyswietlaczaWagi_4linie(WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogWitaj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogZaloguj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.PustaLinia, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogNrOperatora);
                    string NrOperatora = KomunikacjaSieciowa.OdczytDanychZWagi(OdczytZWagi.Kom_ZatwierdzoneF1);
                    //int NrOperatora_int = Convert.ToInt32(NrOperatora);
                    break;
// here goes next case etc
```

Here starts my problem - communication takes place only once and the operation requires data on the terminal. Before the operator enters data program ends.
How to change the code / loop / add a timer to repeated communication to achieve a certain status?
More specifically, as in this passage:

```
case 'B':
                    KomunikacjaSieciowa.WysylkaDoWyswietlaczaWagi_4linie(WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogWitaj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogZaloguj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.PustaLinia, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogNrOperatora);
                    string NrOperatora = KomunikacjaSieciowa.OdczytDanychZWagi(OdczytZWagi.Kom_ZatwierdzoneF1);
```

repeat "string NrOperatora" depending on the returned data?

Where's the best place to make loop?? Maybe I should use thread??

Comment: `KomunikacjaSieciowa.WysylkaDoWyswietlaczaWagi_4linie(WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogWitaj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogZaloguj, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.PustaLinia, WysylkaDoWyswietlacza_Komunikaty.LogNrOperatora);` **Argh**

Comment: +1, you just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `stream.BeginRead` and checking the status when reads are complete is the best way so if the status is not OK you can call `stream.BeginRead` to the same method so it will be a loop calling here self until status is OK

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed example?